# Can we have image sliderview and icons in one activity?

Tags: android

I am trying to  write code for an activity which looks like this image. On top of my screen I want an image sliderview along with some icons below the sliderview as shown in the picture. How do I do this?

[image].

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done as tutorial for one app: I've loaded the images on the center, and I change them not with pointers but with 'Go' and 'Back' buttons inside a RelativeLayout for moving the images, but you can chage it as you want. I have a centered button with 'Finish' and a label with one title in the bottom.
As you'll see this is a example with no previews or icons, but maybe this is a code from what you can start your own.

The tutorial.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Notificacion" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:src="@drawable/guia1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/img1"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:text="@string/back"
        android:textColor="#088A08"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="#088A08"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="back"
        android:text="@string/fin"
        android:textColor="#088A08"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my class is named Tutorial.java, that implements OnClickListener. Here I load the several images from the drawable folder and one text for each one.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Tutorial extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

ImageView foto;
TextView tv;
int[] fotoId = {R.drawable.yourimage01, R.drawable.yourimage02, R.drawable.yourimage03, R.drawable.yourimage04, R.drawable.yourimage05, R.drawable.yourimage06, R.drawable.yourimage07}; 
String[] textos = {"Text for image 01", "Text for image 02", "Text for image 03", "Text for image 04", "Text for image 05", "Text for image 06", "Text for image 07",};
int i = 0;
int total;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial);

    Button next= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_next);
    Button back= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_back);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    foto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    total = fotoId.length;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    int id = view.getId();
    if(id == R.id.button_back) {
        i++;
        if(i == total){
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if(id == R.id.button_next) {
        i--;
        if(i == -1){
            i = total -1;
        }
    }
    foto.setImageResource(fotoId[i]);
    tv.setText(textos[i]);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void back(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Indice.class );
    startActivity(i);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Both answers helped me a lot. But, dear friend Xose Sanchez, in your code there is a class called indice what we will have in that class because it is showing error while I am trying your code. Can you help me out.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. This is another activity that I call with the back button, the index and main activity of this app; you can chage the activity that you call, or even delete that button if you don't need it. It just implements the back; if you do don't forget to delete the button on the .xml

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [this](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) library for your purpose. Just add its dependency and set it for top of tour activity then fill the rest with icons or everthing else you want.