# Android SlideShow View

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imageview, android-animation, android-imageview

I want to show 4 images like a slide show with translate (right to left) animation.
So I used `ViewPager` with 4 `Fragment`s, and thread for automatic navigation to the next `Fragment`.
Everything was fine except navigation from the last item to the first.
In that case `ViewPager` scroll all `Fragment`s (from left to right) to the first one, and this is the problem.
I need something like infinite navigating (right to left).

---

So what alternatives of `ViewPager` for doing this there are?

Comment: This is a similar question and answer. See if it is useful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36005236/3668646

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out , you can achieve using this

https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager

hope it helps :)

Comment: Looks exactly what I need. I'll try and accept your answer later. Thank you.

Comment: so, could I navigate with animation through this InfiniteViewPager in the code?

Comment: yes you can using pagetransformer see this https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: @pratic I used **vp.setCurrentItem(item, true);** in the thread, and it works. But some bug appear: After replacing with another fragment and than back replacing to fragment with **InfiniteViewPager** - Fragments with Image are white (Images are not set), and after couple seconds it started to show correct fragments with images.